# TextView matches all width

Tags: android

I set `TextView` to be left of `ImageView`, but why does it cover all width? There is no difference if I set `android:layout_alignParentRight` and still matches parent?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/removeButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/remove_playlist"
            android:layout_height="25dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            tools:text="tttttttttttt ttttttt tttttttt tttttttttttt tttttt ttttttt tttttttt ttttttttt"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/removeButton"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@id/removeButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use attribute `toLeftOf` not `alignRight`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        tools:text="tttttttttttt ttttttt tttttttt tttttttttttt tttttt ttttttt tttttttt ttttttttt"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

`alignRight` aligns two views right with each other

Comment: oh forgot.. not my day

Comment: I know, it just allows to mark after some time (~10-15 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to remove

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

in your ImageView and replace

```
android:layout_alignRight="@id/removeButton"
android:layout_alignEnd="@id/removeButton"
```

by

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/removeButton"
```

in yout TextView

Answer (score 0):

Just making a little ajust to @Farid answer the attributes are toLeftOf and toStartOf. The toEndOf attribute can be used with the toRightOf attribute:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        tools:text="tttttttttttt ttttttt tttttttt tttttttttttt tttttt ttttttt tttttttt ttttttttt"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/removeButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```